# Wrong shape display with North_Pole_Azimuthal_Equidistant projection

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I need to create a map that displays the breeding and wintering ground of a bird species that has a circular arctic breeding distribution and winters in Africa. The map should lool pretty much like this:

[image]

However, the graticules are not correctly displayed. Depending on scale and frame one or two are missing.

I use the following projection: North_Pole_Azimuthal_Equidistant

Basic layers are graticules and land shapes from naturalearthdata.com. Is there maybe something wrong with the basic shapes and is there another free alternative?

I created grid-lines myself with Vector > Research tools > gridlines too and also tried the grid function from the MMQGIS package but but doesn´t help and gives the same problem.

Comment: Once you get beyond the equator all bets are off

Comment: Ben, this might as well be pointing you in the wrong direction, but for what its worth: there is a great javascript library called D3 to work with projections and displaying data on it. (only if you do know some javascript) To give an idea: https://www.jasondavies.com/maps/

Comment: Can you check your issue against this fix: https://hub.qgis.org/issues/7596

Comment: Thanks for the link. I am afraid my knowledge about QGIS is not deep enough to understand the solution of the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The North Pole projection can not display the South Pole correctly, it would be in infinity.

It works for me this way:

1. Load the 10 degree grid form Natural Earth
2. Create a new polygon shapefile layer
3. Draw a rectangle containing the latitudes from 90N to 60S
4. Clip the grid to the rectangle
5. Densify the geometry with 360 points
6. Reproject the grid to a new file in EPSG:102016
7. Load the 110m land shapefile from natural Earth
8. Delete the Antarctic
9. Reproject the land layer to EPSG:102016
10. Remove all layers except the results of step 6 and 9
11. Set Project CRS from Layer
12. Switch On-the-fly reprojection **OFF**

and you will get this picture:

[image]

Comment: I clipped away the area north of the South pole and also tried to reproject manually but it still results in the same error. Do you have any further idea?

Comment: Did you densify the grid as well? There should be at leat 360 points on every latitude to get nice curved lines after reprojection.

Comment: Yes, I tried to densify the grid too but it didn´t help.

Comment: Thanks for your great effort and the detailed step-by-step explanation! It worked and made my day : )

Comment: What step did you miss before?